# WUBI not present in 16.04 download

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit

I recently downloaded 16.04 onto a CD, but system will not boot from CD as WUBI is not present in download.  Any ideas as to how to correct this?

Comment: Wubi is not necessary to boot from CD. But there are [community supported versions](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases) if you need Wubi. see [Wubi info](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info)

Answer (score 3):

I read somewhere a while back that it was a choice by the Ubuntu devs. Nothing you can do about it.

> From the looks of it, Ubuntu 15.04 is the last ISO that comes with
>   Wubi, but fortunately we'll get a better tool in the future.

Source: http://news.softpedia.com/news/deprecated-wubi-tool-mysteriously-survives-on-ubuntu-images-until-today-489837.shtml#ixzz48sJV6pt7

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus